# Iterate over all bits of byte in C#

Tags: c#, binary, byte

I am working on a C# application. I have a byte variable, i want to iterate over all bits of it.

```
byte var = 3;
System.Collections.BitArray bits = new System.Collections.BitArray(var);
Console.WriteLine("Length of collection : " + bits.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bits[i]);
}
```

This code gives me the following output:

```
Length of collection : 3
False
False
False
```

But as the binary representation of 3 is 00000011 so i expect the following output

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
```

What am i doing wrong ? How can i achieve the required output

Comment: You only initialize the `BitArray` with a length of 3... You should use `BitArray(byte[])` constructor

Comment: So what should i do ? @BiesiGrr

Comment: The method signature for the BitArray constructor you are using is `BitArray(int length)`. So you are saying "I want a new BitArray of length 3", when you want to be saying "I want a new BitArray which is the bits of the integer 3". Very different. You first need to get the bytes and put those in instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the [`BitArray(int length)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_BitArray__ctor_System_Int32_) constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the BitArray class that can hold the specified number of bit values, which are initially set to false.

So you're creating a `BitArray` of length 3, not a `BitArray` which contains the bits from the integer value 3.

You want the [`BitArray(byte[] bytes)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_BitArray__ctor_System_Byte___) constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the BitArray class that contains bit values copied from the specified array of bytes.

```
byte var = 3;
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { var });
Console.WriteLine("Length of collection : " + bits.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bits[i]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Length of collection : 8
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Thanks @canton7, it worked. Just one more thing, why i am getting True at the start ? should not it be at the end ? as the binary representation is "00000011"

Comment: @WaleedNaveed Because it indexes from the least-significant bit, not the most-significant bit