# What does the `var` inside the curly braces mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, var

What does the `var` inside the curly braces mean in C#?

E.g. there is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58995757/iterate-over-all-bits-of-byte-in-c-sharp).

Below the question there is a piece of code in an answer:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { var });
```

I have never seen the `var` being used like that and I was not able to find anything about it by googling.

When I try to run the following:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[] { var };
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Compilation error (line 7, col 34): The name 'var' does not exist in the current context
```

I am using the `.NET 4.7.2`. Probably a different version of the `.NET` is needed?

Comment: previous line with `byte var = 3;` in linked question gives you an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the referenced question there is a variable declared with name `var` (this is possible because `var` is not one of the [reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) in C#).

This syntax:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { var };
```

Is for [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)  which creates an array of `byte` containing one item (`var`). So in your case you are getting an error because there is no variable/field/property with name `var` accessible in the scope.

Answer (score 3):

It's a variable named `var`. If you look in the original source:

```cs
byte var = 3;
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { var });
```

`var` is what's called a ["contextual keyword"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords). If you use it as an identifier - in this case, a `byte` variable named `var` - then it functions like an identifier, not a keyword. So there's no special meaning here, it's just initiating a `BitArray` based on a 1-element `byte` array with `3` as the sole element.

Answer (score 1):

By `var` they probably meant variable in that case. You are getting an error that var doesn't exist in the current context:

From the original post:

```
byte var = 3;
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { var });
```

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, I agree with you. Thank you for clarifying this.